# How make summation for a series which contains arbitrary elements

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, summation

I am studding a [research paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/js/2016/6319830/) in winch author presented a analytical model for set traversal and different cases of time complexity.
I am not understanding the one point in the model that is related to summation formulation equation n# 18.

$\frac{m_1 + 1}{2}t + \frac{l_2 + 1}{2}t + .... + \frac{l_n + 1}{2}t$

$ = \frac{1}{2} \bigr(m_1 + n + \sum_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a\bigr) t$

Why $l_2 + l_3 + l_4 + ..... + l_n = \sum_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a$

why its not $\sum_{a=2}^{n} l_a$

Comment: ...because they wanted to write it like that?

Comment: Because the authors are innumerate?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Or, better, replace $a$ by $i$ rather than $i$ by $a$.

Comment: He actually does it in all the other equations as well. For example, look at equation (13):
$$
\frac{1}{l_2} \sum_{i = 1}^{l_2}t_i = \frac{l_2 + 1}{2}t
$$
His l's are already decided in the definition of set $A_i$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sloppy notation.

The author intended $\sum\limits_{a \in \{l_2, l_3, .... , l_n\}} a$ which would be the same thing as $\sum_{a=2}^n l_a$.

However I'd argue that $\sum\limits_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a$ is not actually *wrong* per se.

The notation for $\sum$ is $\sum\limits_{\text{some condition}} term = $ "the sum of all the $terms$ for which that condition is true".

(A practical example of this would be $\sum\limits_{a|24;a\in \mathbb N} a   = $ the sum of all the divisors of $24=1 + 2 + 3 + 4+ 6 + 8 +12 + 24$.)

This means the familiar $\sum\limits_{a=2}^n l_a$ *actually* means $\sum\limits_{a\in \{2,3,4,...n\}} l_a$ and that $_{a=2}^n$ is just shorthand for $a\in \{2.....n\}$.

Except when were we ever actually *TAUGHT* that $_{a=2}^n$ is just shorthand for $a \in \{2.....n\}$?  Well, maybe you were but *I* never was.  I had to pick it up on the streets...

Anyway,  if $_{a=2}^n$ is proper shorthand for $a \in \{2,.... n\}$ then isn't it okay that $_{a=l_2}^{l_n}$ proper shorthand for $a \in \{l_2, .... l_n\}$?

Meh... maybe.  I admit it looks weird and we have to think but... is it any more weird than $_{a=2}^n$?

(That was rhetorical.)

(Anyway, welcome to learning mathematics on the street.)

====ADDENDUM====

In a comment in Marcus Scheurer's answer, I realize that $\sum\limits_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a$ could just as legitimately be interpretated as $l_2 + (l_2 + 1) + (l_2 + 3) + ..... +(l_2 + \lfloor l_n - l_2\rfloor)$.

It would take a bit bit of a bean-counter mind to interpret it that way if the individual $l_i$ values weren't specifically spelled out.

But that *is* a technical and correct interpretation.

So...  was the author wrong or right?  Arguments can be made both ways.

But it's what the author *did*.  And the author clearly meant it to be interpreted as $\sum\limits_{i=2}^n l_i$.

Those are the existential facts.  What we do with them is up to us.

Answer (score 3):

Your doubts are reasonable and your proposal is correct. The formula (18) in the referred paper and some more show all  the same kind of typos (or miscalculations).

> We have
>   \begin{align*}
> l_2 + l_3 + l_4 + ..... + l_n\color{blue}{=\sum_{a=2}^{n} l_a}
> \end{align*}
>
> and not  $l_2 + l_3 + l_4 + ..... + l_n = \sum_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a$, since $$\sum_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a=\sum_{l_2\leq a\leq l_n}a$$

Comment: Is the notation $\sum\limits_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a = \sum\limits_{a\in \{l_2...l_n\}} a$ really any more of an abuse of notation than $\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n} l_i = \sum\limits_{i \in \{2....n\}} l_i$?

Comment: @fleablood: The author might have somewhat of this kind in mind, but as it is written we have $\sum_{i=l_2}^{n}l_i=l_2+(l_2+1)+\cdots+l_n$ which is *not the  same* as $\sum_{i\in\{2,\ldots,n\}}l_i$.

Comment: That's not what we have written.  We have $\sum\limits_{a=l_2}^{l_n} a$ which can be interpreted either as $l_2 + (l_2 +1) + (l_2 + 3)+.... + l_n$ (all assuming that $l_n$ is a positive integer value larger than $l_2$).  Or as $l_2 + l_3 + l_4 + .... + l_n$.  Obviously in context the author meant the latter. And I agree he should have been clearer with the more common $\sum\limits_{i=2}^n l_i$.  But can we really claim that that is "wrong" when $\sum\limits_{i=2}^n$ to mean $\sum\limits_{i\in\{2,...,n\}}$ is every bit as informal and relays just as much on "being clear in context"?

Comment: @fleablood: We have $\sum_{a=l_2}^{l_n}a=\sum_{l_2\leq a \leq l_n}a$ which is not the same as $\sum_{a\in\{2,\ldots,n\}}l_a$. You might want to check formula (2.2), (2.3) and (2.4) in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*.

Comment: true...writing $_{a=j}^k$ is taken to mean $j\le a \le k; a-j\in \mathbb Z$. But is that written in stone? I agree with you I'm inclined to call what the author did wrong and ambiguous at best.  Is interpreting $_{a=j}^k$ to mean $j \le a \le k$ any more legitimate? What if $j$ and $k$ aren't integers?  Why is the 'step' assumed to be $1$?  What if $k < j$. etc. ... well, theres a lot to be said for convention and we do have answers to all of those. But there's also something to be said about interpretation through context. (A subtle aspect is $a$ is not usually taken to be an integral index.)

Comment: @fleablood: I don't think it's useful to undermine a standard notation in order to bring some  typos or  miscalculations in a wanted form. I suggest to  enjoy the whole chapter 2 in some detail (btw I deeply  appreciate Don Knuth who is one of the  great). This might lead to a slightly different point of view.

Comment: I don't see why you think I am "undermining" anything. And I don't *like* what the author did.  But I don't think it was a "typo".  Just unconventional. (And pointless as the conventional is just as easy and clearer).  But not *wrong* (but  ambiguous).